# What could cause a generic Comparator (or Comparable) to have significantly worse performance than a non-generic one?

Tags: java, performance, generics, comparator, comparable

I have an implementation of the A* pathfinding algorithm, defined to operate over anything that implements the following interface:

```
public interface Pathable<N extends Pathable<N>> extends Comparable<N>
```

Obviously, there are a great deal of comparisons being performed during the pathfinding, primarily to make sure that the next "best" `Pathable` is the one the algorithm actually considers next. Internally, the nodes are stored as a priority queue.

In this specific case, the `Pathable` nodes in question are tiles in a hexagonal grid, as such:

```
public interface Tile<T extends Tile> extends Pathable<T>
```

And there is an abstract base class implementing `Tile` which contains the implementation of the comparison (among other things common to all Tiles in this program):

```
public abstract class TileBase<T extends Tile<T>> implements Tile<T>
{
    @Override
    public final int compareTo(final T pathable)
    {
        // If our cost to reach the destination is lower, order us before etc...
    }
}
```

One of the concrete implementations of this class is as such:

```
public class TilePreview extends TileBase<TilePreview>
```

The issue I have is thus: If I supply the pathfinder with a `Comparator` instead of relying on the natural ordering from `Comparable`, performance improves by as much as a factor of five! Such a `Comparator` is defined as follows:

```
public class TilePreviewComparator implements Comparable<TilePreview>
{
    @Override
    public final int compare(final TilePreview n0, final TilePreview n1)
    {
        // If n0's cost to reach the destination is lower than n1's, order it before etc...
    }
}
```

There are a number of different kinds of `Tile` which are compared in the same way, and so in the interest of reducing code replication I simply made a generic `Comparator`:

```
public abstract class TileComparator<N extends Pathable<N>> implements Comparator<N>
{
    @Override
    public final int compare(final N n0, final N n1)
    {
        // If n0's cost to reach the destination is lower than n1's, order it before etc...
    }
}
```

Doing this however causes performance to tank again. I have spent a number of days debugging this confusing issue. I have verified that both approaches result in the same amount of "work", for example the exact same number of comparisons are performed in all cases, `Comparable` or `Comparator`. I have verified that the pathfinding results are identical. I have tried a number of different priority queue implements, primarily the collections framework's own PriorityQueue and FastUtil's ObjectHeapPriorityQueue, and while the implementations have slightly different performance from one another, they still show the same significant discrepancy between using the generic `Comparator`/`Comparable` vs non-generic.

I have reached the limit of my knowledge when it comes to investigating a problem like this and was curious if anybody else had any ideas. Technically I have a solution which is to simply use the non-generic `Comparator` approach, but it doesn't sit right with me. For one, it is not the most elegant of the choices, even if it is the most performant. Perhaps more importantly however, I hate not knowing *why* the problem is occurring in the first place!

Any insights are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please show a [mcve].